# How to replace all special characters except for underscore and numbers in java?

Tags: java

I want to replace all special characters from the string object BusDetails below with a blank "" except for _(underscore) and numbers in java ?

```
BusDetails=BusDetails.replaceAll("&#151;", "").replaceAll("\\s+","_").replaceAll("ROUTE", "BUS").replaceAll("-", "_");
```

Comment: How about `BusDetails = BusDetails.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");`?

Comment: try `.replaceAll("[\\W]", "")`. `[\\W]` matches any character that is not a alphanumeric & underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
BusDetails=BusDetails.replaceAll("(\\W|^_)*", "");
```

The pattern `(\\W|^_)` matches any non-word character. Additionally it excludes `_`.

Answer (score 4):

```
BusDetails = BusDetails.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]", "");
```

Using the regex pattern `"[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]"` we can replace all special characters (symbols) from the string except letters, numbers and '_'.

Comment: Code-only answers are very seldom helpful. Please explain how your snippet solves the task. For us all to learn.

Comment: Using "[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]" this regex pattern we can replace all special characters(symbols) from the string except characters, numbers and '_'.

Suppose
 BusDetails=BusDetails.replaceAll("Amol&#_151;", "").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]", ""); 
it will return String "Amol_151"

Comment: Thx, Amol Birajdar. I put the explanation in the answer, where it belongs, for you. Next time do that yourself, please. To improve an answer you have already posted, use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48315663/edit) under the answer.

Comment: Oops, I got only the first version of your comment in there. Your turn now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
BusDetails=BusDetails.replaceAll("[^_0-9]+", "");
```

This retain integer numbers but not decimals (add a "." for that)